# Removing First Element in Char * Array Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have a variable `buf` stored as `char *buf` this variable comes out to be an ID that looks something like `/3B494538-9120-46E0-95D4-51A4CF5712A1`. I want to remove the first element of the `char *buf` so that `/3B494538-9120-46E0-95D4-51A4CF5712A1` becomes `3B494538-9120-46E0-95D4-51A4CF5712A1`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an array that reuses `buf`'s memory:

```
char *nonCopyBuf = buf + 1;
```

or allocate new memory storage:

```
char *copyBuf = malloc(strlen(buf));
memcpy(copyBuf, buf + 1, strlen(buf));
//...
free(copyBuf);
```

Comment: (strlen(buf) -1) ? maybe ? since new array should be 1 char less

Comment: @ColdSteel it is also needed to copy a `0`-value byte that terminates sting and is not included in `strlen()` result.